# Hard in calculating predictor‘s Relative Importance for GAM?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, generalized-additive-model, importance

Although there is no agreement upon "relative importance for predictors" with (even) linear models (one possible definition: [lmg method](https://advstats.psychstat.org/book/mregression/importance.php)), I would still want to know whether there are some acceptable methods to do it, if I build a Generalized Additive Model.

It's a natural question about which predictor is more important or useful (quantitatively, e.g., using percentage), isn't it?

I found `relaimpo` package can calculate several relative importance metrics for the linear model, but it can not handle GAM models (see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495653/different-r-squared-in-relaimpo-and-mgcv-for-one-model)).
Here is an example:

```
library(relaimpo)
library(mgcv)
gam1 <- gam(mpg ~ s(drat) + s(wt) + s(qsec), data = mtcars, method = "REML")
summary(gam1)
```

From the `summary()` result, we can see which predictor is "significant" by p-value:

```
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
          edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(drat) 1.000  1.000  0.523 0.476069    
s(wt)   2.487  3.028 21.950 1.59e-08 ***
s(qsec) 1.000  1.000 15.241 0.000545 ***
```

But we don't know their "relative importance", for example, can we get the following information?

```
`wt` has a relative importance of 60%, 
`qsec` has a relative importance of 30%, 
`drat` has a relative importance of 10%.
```

What's worse, because GAM doesn't have a real R-squared, I suppose `lmg` method cannot be applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `caret` package provides one answer. With the default `tuneGrid` and `trainControl`,

```
library(caret)
data("mtcars")
gam1 <- train(
  mpg ~ drat + wt + qsec, 
  data = mtcars, 
  method = "gam"
)
```

and you can then apply `varImp`.

```
varImp(gam1)
## gam variable importance
##      Overall
## wt     100.0
## qsec    26.4
## drat     0.0
```

For sort of the percentage-idea that you wanted, you can resize the returned object:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- varImp(gam1)
x$importance %>%
  mutate(
    Variable = rownames(.), Overall = Overall / sum(Overall) * 100
  ) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Overall)) %>%
  select(Variable, Overall)
##   Variable Overall
## 1       wt   79.09
## 2     qsec   20.91
## 3     drat    0.00
```

Because the default will not tune splines or degrees of freedom, you should check how to do these in the `caret` package. The `method = 'gam'` will call the `mgcv` package, but there are [plenty other options](https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#generalized-additive-model). For instance if you used `method = 'gamSpline'`, it would tune over the degrees of freedom, and give a different `varImp` result.

Be wary of what `caret` is doing under the hood, however---if there are not many distinct values in a predictor, it may turn the term into linear.

Comment: I would note that `varImp` is essentially renormalises the $p$-values associated to the terms to get "importance scores". That is *one* way of defining variable importance but I woudn't consider it universal or the best in all scenarios. (`varImp` in this example use-cases more less does: `S <- summary(gam1); S$s.table[,'p-value'] |> (function(x){-log10(x)})() |> (function(x){ z=x-min(x); 100*z/max(z)})()` to get the "variable importance. Nothing wrong but nothing magical either.)